# outlook 2013 and windows 8 - file changed while outlook not in use

Tags: windows, outlook, windows-8.1

I have searched the web, including StackOverflow and have not yet found an answer so, i'm hoping someone here will know...

I sync my Outlook PST file (and others) between my laptop and a flash drive to have the file on both my laptop and desktop and a backup using a simple file copy app (FreeFileSync).

Outlook is closed during this operation.

When comparing files prior to syncing from the desktop to the flash drive, if I have used Outlook since the last sync, they file on the desktop is always "newer".  Doing the same operation from the flash drive to the laptop (win8.1), the compare yields "both files have changed" even though Outlook was not explicitly running on the laptop since the last sync.  The question is, "what on the laptop might be 'touching' the PST file such that it has a newer date/time than the date/time of its last sync?"

My guess is that something related to the Win8.1 Mail app is involved.  When i ran through the initial setup of this laptop, it was my first experience with 8.1.  I am pretty sure I started the Mail app but later realized it was going to conflict in some way with my using Outlook.  Any more specific pointers you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might have already tried this but open the task manager and see if outlook is running. I know outlook continues to run for about 30 seconds after being closed.

Downloaded [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), lunch it, and go to find(menu) -> "Find Handle or DLL" and then navigate to the PST file. See if an executable has the desktop pst open.

Comment: Thanks Sunsetquest.  It's worth trying.  I'll post back here when i have done it.

Comment: Using Process Explorer, and the find handle or dll..., it does not appear that anything has it open.  Looking at the file's date/time, it appears it was "touched" when i logged on to the computer (even though Outlook does not open automatically via the Startup folder and i've gone through the "run" keys in regedit as well.  My current suspicion is the antivirus.  Maybe it's scanning the PST on login.

Comment: It could be the antivirus but I would not think the antivirus would modify the PST each time it is scanned - it is possible though.  There are lots of places that startup stuff can be hidden.  Try autoruns for that. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx It is by Mark Russinovich - the same guy who made Process Explorer. Hopefully you find it.

Comment: Another think you can try is moving the PST file to another location and reboot to see what happens. It possible that whatever program is opening it will not be able to find it and it will not be able to modify it on startup.

Comment: i tried to rename it and was informed that rundll32 has it open.  now, how do i figure out WHY?

Comment: later that same night...  it was the mail applet in this case but not solving the entire problem.  It appears that Outlook is somehow opening "in the background" on startup though it is NOT in the startup folder under %programdata% nor under %appdata%.  Just ran "autoruns" and there's a lot to digest there.